# Creating a Table in SQL with relations from other tables

Tags: sql

I want to create a table which contains key fields from 3 other tables.

Assume the table names are

- student_info
- teacher_info
- subject_info

In each table is a key field.

For the first table (student_info) it is studentID.
For the second table (teacher_info) it is teacherID.
for the third table (subject_info) it is subID.

I would like to create a fourth table that links these in SQL. Can I use the code as below:

```
CREATE TABLE sub_link (
   student_info.studentID,
   teacher_info.teacherID,
   subject_info.subID
   );
```

**As in I want to create the table so that I can say that a specific teacherID teaches these subjectIDs and these studentIDs. I want to use them as references to records.**

Comment: Probably not  - But the name of the database would be handy? Also why not just try it?

Comment: Are you familiar with foreign keys?

Comment: You are in the right track.  All you are missing is add to foreign key to restrict what values can be entered into the new table.